# Getting values from table in DB2

Tags: java, database, jdbc, db2, db2-400

I want to get the values  from a table using db2 and print out the results.

This is the code I am trying to use to do that:

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class connection {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        try {
            Class.forName("COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Please include Classpath  Where your DB2 Driver is located");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("DB2 driver is loaded successfully");
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rset=null;
        boolean found=false;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2:sabarish","db2admin","Murugasaranam");
            if (conn != null)
            {
                System.out.println("DB2 Database Connected");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Db2 connection Failed ");
            }
            pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE TABSCHEMA= 'STD' AND TABNAME= 'inventory'");
            rset=pstmt.executeQuery();
            if(rset!=null)
            {

                while(rset.next())
                {
                    found=true;
                    System.out.println("Class Code: "+rset.getString("clcode"));
                    System.out.println("Name: "+rset.getString("name"));
                }
            }
            if (found ==false)
            {
                System.out.println("No Information Found");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("DB2 Database connection Failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

It only prints out column names. Instead of column names, what query statement can I use to get the results? `db2 select * from store.inventory`
does not seem to work as well.

Comment: I'm not a DB2 expert by any means, but why did you omit the database name from your JDBC query?

Comment: What's the exception ? What exactly is the problem ? not working means ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the examples I saw online followed this format. I am pretty new to it myself. I just started working with DB2 today.

Comment: @javaguy it does not print out the values. It just gives the column names.

Comment: What happens when you run your code?  Do you get an error?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it just lists the column names. Not the values.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  How could `getDouble()` return text?

Comment: The above code is just an example. My focus is only on the query statement. I  am trying to find out how to query a database similar to that example using db2. The 'db2 select * from store.inventory' and `  SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE TABSCHEMA= 'STD' AND TABNAME= 'inventory'  are the main focus.

Comment: if your are on iseries db2 SYSCAT.COLUMNS  doesnt exist. Use syscolumns.

Comment: you should change jdbc:mysql to jdbc:db2  in your example;

Comment: @MustafaDOGRU I modified my question. The first code  I put earlier on was just an example, this is the actual code I had.

Comment: Please modify your question and write exact error you are getting on this.

Comment: @rjaydee : which table you use in prepareStatement ? store.inventory or SYSCAT.COLUMNS. SYSCAT.COLUMNS table not have clcode. Could you updated exact sql in prepareStatement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `select * from STD.inventory`